# URL with "@" parameter automatically transformed to "<span>@</span>"

Tags: android, character-encoding, url-encoding

I am sending an activation email to my users that looks like this:

```
Please, click here in order to validate your email address and complete the activation
of your account.
```

Where the words "click here" have a link to this URL:

```
https://example.com/users/activate?username=myemail@example.com&regid=APA91bGSRWxbsClcN9-SY
```

It works well in most cases, but one costumer that opens the link with the Android browsers below automatically transforms the URL to `https://example.com/users/activate?username=myemail<span>@</span>example.com&regid=APA91bGSRWxbsClrN9-SY`

From my app log I receive a request for `https://example.com/users/activate?username=myemail%3Cspan%3E@%3C/span%3E...` which causes the app to break.

How can I prevent this?

**BROWSER CONF:**

“Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; HUAWEI P6 S-U06 Build/HuaweiP6S-U06)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36”

Comment: what does the link code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by replacing the symbol "@" in the URL by the equivalent encoding "%40".

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial on [HTML URL Encoding](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm). The URL Encode for the symbol "@" is     "%40" so use:

> https://example.com/users/activate?username=myemail%40example.com&regid=APA91bGSRWxbsClcN9-SY